# How to search and copy results with file structure?

Tags: batch-file, search, cmd, copy

I am trying to find a way to search a directory for files by name, then copy the found files to an output directory. Because the files will have the same file name, I'm wondering if I can copy the folder structure as well, or alternatively append the filename with its parent folder name (i.e. folder\file.txt becomes folder-file.txt)

The search I'm using is a basic dir call:

```
dir file.xml /s
```

Can I do what I'm trying with only cmd? I would be ok using this in a batch script as well, though I believe the syntax is the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would probably do this with robocopy (built in to newer versions of Windows). Something like this should do the trick...

```
robocopy.exe /S C:\FromDir C:\ToDir file.xml
```

Answer (score 1):

This will copy the `file.xml` files that match on `c:` and keep the folder structure intact, to `d:\results`

```
xcopy "c:\file.xml" "d:\results\" /s
```